# Export to Excel: Ho to prevent splitting data in Last Page Footer

Tags: java, jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I have a problem, i generate XLSX with JasperReports, but if i want print document, he's break page not correctly.
I need last page footer not split.

I can't use *ignorePagination* or *ignoreMargins*, because they delete space (delete page break) and my last page footer split on another page...

Split type on last page footer set *Prevent*

*What do you recommend to me?*

```
JasperReports library - 6.3.0
iReport - 5.6.0
Java - 1.8
MS Excel - 2016
```

My report design:

[image]

The generated *XLSX* file looks like:

[image]

You can see, if page break move on 1 cell down, page print correctly, but i can't open every document for correction him

The *splitType* for *lastPageFooter* is set as ***Prevent***.

Java code

```
public void createReport(Map<String,Object> dataMap, HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request){
    String pathToServletRoot = request.getSession(true).getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
    String sourceFileName = pathToServletRoot + "/resources/template/jasper/reportT12.jasper";
    try {
        ArrayList<DataBean> dataList = dataBeanArrayList(dataMap);
        JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanColDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(dataList);
        Map parameters = new HashMap();
        try {
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(sourceFileName,
                    parameters, beanColDataSource);

            JRXlsxExporter exporter = new JRXlsxExporter();
            ByteArrayOutputStream xlsxReport = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
            exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(xlsxReport));

            SimpleXlsxReportConfiguration configuration = new SimpleXlsxReportConfiguration();
            configuration.setOnePagePerSheet(false);
            configuration.setDetectCellType(true);

            exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);

            exporter.exportReport();
            response.getOutputStream().write(xlsxReport.toByteArray());
        } catch (JRException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        CrmLogger.error(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Last footer page: split or not split](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39788765/last-footer-page-split-or-not-split)

Comment: Andrew, it is a bad idea to repost the same question

Comment: Last footer page: split or not split have little information, this question more correctly and have more information for resolve my problem, i mean maybe close "Last footer page: split or not split" question and stay this ? I am sorry but i think this, not so bad idea

Comment: Please, check my comments on your original post. It is not enough information to help you. Last time I made example and it works well for me. You can delete your first post.

Comment: Yes of course I checked your comments, but this not help... maybe Excel break page another... i mean Excel stay break line before space, if break line stay in mid space it's gonna be right. I add in googleDisc screen iReport design

Comment: Andrew, your *jrxml* file is huge. You should prepare the small example to reproduce the problem. BTW, did you try to export report as *pdf* file, for example? Is it ok?

Comment: Ok, i think i have answer, but next problem ...

Why ? How fix it ?  https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzTdu-mjsc2idmY4aUVhLWpPUzg

Comment: No I don't try to export my file in PDF, but i think about it now

Comment: In pdf it's OK, no problem